# What kind of content/data does "fallocate" command generate?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, dd, swap, fallocate-command

When is executed the `sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile` command, then 2 GB is created, but with that kind of content or data? Can be it customized? If yes How?. I did do some research but there are no details about this. I want to know if is good use `fallocate` for `swap file` purpose.

For example `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=N` creates the data filled with Zeros, not sure if `swap file` asks for mandatorily the data with zeros - in the `swap file` tutorials did not mention of this.

Comment: For filesystems which support the fallocate system call, preallocation is done quickly by allocating blocks and marking them as uninitialized, requiring no IO to the data blocks. This is much faster than creating a file by filling it with zeroes. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swap files do not need to full of zeros.  The kernel keeps track of what blocks are being used.

However, `man mkswap` may warn you against using `fallocate`:

> Note  that a swap file must not contain any holes.  Using `cp(1)` to create the file is not acceptable.  Neither is use of `fallocate(1)` on filesystems  that  support  preallocated  files, such as XFS or ext4, or on copy-on-write filesystems like btrfs.  It is recommended to  use  `dd(1)` and  `/dev/zero` in these cases.  Please read notes from `swapon(8)` before adding a swap file to copy-on-write filesystems.

(Not all versions of the manpage include that)

Further `swapon` says:

> The swap file implementation in the kernel expects to be able to  write to  the  file directly, without the assistance of the filesystem.  This is a problem on preallocated files (e.g.  `fallocate(1)`) on  filesystems like XFS or ext4, and on copy-on-write filesystems like btrfs.

Another version of the manpage says

> Preallocated  files created by `fallocate(1)` may be interpreted as files with holes too depending of the filesystem.   Preallocated  swap  files are supported on XFS since Linux 4.18.

So the question as to whether you can use `fallocate` to create swapfiles very much depends on your kernel and your file system.

In comparison, a simple `dd` will work.

Comment: Thanks, just curious, why some man includes that critical information and others not? I thought the man pages are a standard for all Unix/Linux distributions

Comment: Different versions of the package, different age of the OS... stuff changes :-)

Comment: Interesting for Ubuntu 22.04 does not exist that kind of note anymore - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/mkswap.8.html

Comment: But the swapon manpage does have the XFS comment.

Answer (score 1):

See [Stephen Harris’ answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697424/86440) for details of the suitability of `fallocate` for swap file creation.

As far as the data “created” by `fallocate`, the technical answer depends on the file system being used, but the result is always that when `fallocate` extends the length of a file, the newly-allocated portion of the file will produce zeroes when read (even though it might not contain zeroes on disk). This is described [in the documentation of the related system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html):

> Any subregion within
> the range specified by *offset* and *len* that did not contain data
> before the call will be initialized to zero.